# Return NON-Matched values from the result of XML path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to compare two tables where t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA and t1.ColumnB<>t2.ColumnB. The caveat to this problem is that t2.ColumnB is using a "FOR XML PATH" to concatenate like values from another table (linked server using OPENQUERY).  This all has to be done within a View.

To concatenate the rows, I am using the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CAST(A.CHECK_NUMBER AS nvarchar) [CHECK_NUMBER]
,(
    SELECT B.INVOICE_NUMBER + '|' 
    FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER], 'SELECT * FROM CHECK_LISTING ') B 
    WHERE B.CHECK_NUMBER = A.CHECK_NUMBER 
    AND (NULLIF (B.INVOICE_NUMBER, '') IS NOT NULL) 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) [INVOICE_NUMBER]
, (
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(B.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID)) + '|'
    FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER], 'SELECT * FROM CHECK_LISTING ') B 
    WHERE B.CHECK_NUMBER = A.CHECK_NUMBER 
    AND (NULLIF (B.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID, '') IS NOT NULL) 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) [PURCHASE_ORDER_ID]
FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER], 'SELECT * FROM CHECK_LISTING ') AS A
```

This works perfectly and concatenates just like it needs to.  My problem is that my next view I created was to run that view against a local table to see the difference in the INVOICE_NUMBER.

```
SELECT 
    A.EntryID,
    A.Check#,
    A.CheckDate,
    A.CheckAmount,
    A.VendorID,
    A.VendorName,
    B.INVOICE_NUMBER,
    A.Invoice#
FROM dbo.APChecks AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.CHECKS_Step2 AS B
        ON A.Check#=B.CHECK_NUMBER
WHERE (A.Invoice# != B.INVOICE_NUMBER)
```

When I try to run this, the query takes at least 25+ minutes. I had to stop the query manually.  Some concatenated values are longer than 1000 chars. I was told that it was not possible to INDEX on a dynamic entry like an XML PATH.

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two queries?  Is the first query above used to create a view (e.g. is it the defintion for view `CHECKS_Step2`)?

Comment: Sorry! Yes, CHECKS_Step2 is the first query.  I saved that query in a view so I can refer to it in another view.  

I initially made it into one view, but it took even longer.